# Deploy ERC721 tokens to many addresses

Tags: erc-721, solidity

How to I transfer many of my ERC721 tokens to many addresses?

MyERC721:

```
function mintUniqueTokenTo (
    address _to,
    uint256 _tokenId,               
    string  _tokenURI // Store, receipient's name, grade and program details
) public
{        
    super.mint(_to, _tokenId);        
    super._setTokenURI(_tokenId, _tokenURI);
}
```

Mint to one token is easy:

```
nftInstance.mintUniqueTokenTo(address, tokenId, tokenURI)
```

With many receipients, I thought of creating a distribution contract but solidity cannot accepts array of strings. So I cannot pass it the **tokenIds** and **tokenURIs**

```
addresses[]; //List of receipients of my NFT tokens
tokenIds[];
tokenURIs[];
```

So this is where I'm stuck. Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can approach setting up the ERC721 "token metadata URI".

## 1. Compute URI in code

Since we pass the "addresses" and "tokenIds" as arrays, we can compute the URI string by concatenating the "base_uri" + current tokenId, then set it.

## 2. Create your own data serialisation / deserialisation code.

As you noticed Solidity's ABI ( Application Binary Interface ) does not support handling nested / multi level arrays.

Since a string is already a byte array, ( first 32 bytes contains the length uint256 0x00 to 0x20 / next 0x20 to any contains the actual data ) we can write a custom data parser, either in pure solidity or solidity assembly.

This parser could handle just the tokenURIs or even combine all parameters we need ( address / tokenId / tokenURI ).

Check out [Zoom Src](https://github.com/MCROEngineering/zoom/blob/master/contracts/Zoom.sol) / [Zoom Docs](https://github.com/MCROEngineering/zoom) for an idea on how this is done directly in assembly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [code for Su Squares](https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuNFT.sol)  includes [this nugget](https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/blob/master/contracts/SuNFT.sol#L221-L239):

```
/// @notice A distinct Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) for a given asset.
/// @dev Throws if `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT. URIs are defined in RFC
///  3986. The URI may point to a JSON file that conforms to the "ERC721
///  Metadata JSON Schema".
function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId)
    external
    view
    mustBeValidToken(_tokenId)
    returns (string _tokenURI)
{
    _tokenURI = "https://tenthousandsu.com/erc721/00000.json";
    bytes memory _tokenURIBytes = bytes(_tokenURI);
    _tokenURIBytes[33] = byte(48+(_tokenId / 10000) % 10);
    _tokenURIBytes[34] = byte(48+(_tokenId / 1000) % 10);
    _tokenURIBytes[35] = byte(48+(_tokenId / 100) % 10);
    _tokenURIBytes[36] = byte(48+(_tokenId / 10) % 10);
    _tokenURIBytes[37] = byte(48+(_tokenId / 1) % 10);

}
```

In this approach, the URI is calculated dynamically. You could use a similar approach for the URI and this allows you to use the array approach for your own `mintUniqueTokensTo` function.

^ This assumes you are working with a moderate number of mint operations. For example, OpenSea recently [introduced bundles](https://medium.com/opensea/introducing-bundles-c53c0d04d6b4) transfers (see [one of them here](https://opensea.io/bundles)) which are limited to 30 items. If you are doing something much larger than that you need a more scaleable solution. We can discuss those but it is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ERC721A, which was designed for minting multiple NFTs in one transaction by saving gas.
https://github.com/chiru-labs/ERC721A